# Using Custom iOS AlertView, button closes alert?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented the Custom iOS AlertView from this: https://github.com/wimagguc/ios-custom-alertview

and heres how i implemented it:

```
  CustomIOSAlertView *alertView = [[CustomIOSAlertView alloc] init];
        [alertView setButtonTitles:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cancel", @"Next", nil]];
        [alertView setUseMotionEffects:true];

        [alertView setContainerView:view];
        [alertView show];
```

So the problem is, i haven't called `alertView close` yet it closes with any click on either buttons which isnt what i want

anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, alertView will disappear when you click any button in this alertView.

Comment: how do i make it not default?

Comment: In your custom AlertView, you need to change native code of library. I found it in CustomIOSAlertView.m
    - (void)customIOS7dialogButtonTouchUpInside: (CustomIOSAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Button Clicked! %d, %d", (int)buttonIndex, (int)[alertView tag]);
    [self close];
}